# from_tz - date format issue in oracle from_tz

Tags: sql, oracle

i am getting an issue with from_tz function.

```
select from_tz(cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Etc/GMT') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Minsk'
from dual;
```

output>> `26-FEB-21 05.14.22.000000000 PM EUROPE/MINSK`

but when i am converting it in my desired date format, time is getting reduced with 1 hour.

```
select to_char(from_tz(cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Etc/GMT') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Minsk','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;
```

output>> `26-FEB-2021 16:14:35`

Can you please tell me how to get correct time in above format?

Comment: Can't immediately reproduce; what is your dbtimezone? And sessiontimesone I suppose, for completeness. And which answer is right - I get 16:14 for both? Also... why are you doing `from_tz(cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Etc/GMT')` instead of just using `systimestamp`?

Comment: DBTimezone is GMT only, i tried "select to_char(systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Minsk','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;", But still seeing 1 hour gap when converting in TO_CHAR

Comment: Actually, I get [16:xx for both in 11g](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a471998c809d57b9df91cf5c0420f75b), and [17:xx for both in 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a471998c809d57b9df91cf5c0420f75b) - presumably because of changes to that region between time zone files. Presumably you're seeing this in the same session in the same DB, which is odd - it should at least be consistent. Which DB version and patch level are you on?

Comment: Version 17.3.1.279

Comment: That's your SQL Developer version number; what is the database version? `select * from v$version`

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this at Oracle cloud database with 19с that is run at GMT.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I suppose the OP wants to eventually apply this to other input dates, `SYSDATE` is just for testing and illustration. Which is why he doesn't start with `SYSTIMESTAMP`. Separately from that - why do either `dbtimezone` or `sessiontimezone` matter? The query has nothing to do with either.

Comment: @mathguy - they shouldn't, but as something weird seems to be going on (if this is all in one session) then knowing if dbtimezone is something other than UTC might be interesting, in case there is a bug involved. But no, looks like it isn't relevant.

Comment: @vikaskumar - Clearest "evidence" would be if you can include two values in the output of the same query: `select {the timestamp with time zone} as ts, {the same wrapped within to_char) as str from dual`. So there is no dispute over "is it the same session", "is it run at the same time", etc. Can you please try that (if you haven't already) and let us know?

Comment: Why not simply `systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Minsk'`?

Comment: What is the time zone of database server's operating system? You can get it with `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') FROM dual;` Note, when you run `from_tz(cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Etc/GMT')` then you tell Oracle: "time zone of time zone less `SYDATE` is "Etc/GMT" - is that true?

Comment: Still same issue:                                                                                                    
  select from_tz(cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Etc/GMT') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Minsk' as syst,
to_char(from_tz(cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Etc/GMT') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Minsk','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') eur from dual;                                                            SYST>>26-FEB-21 08.33.29.000000000 PM EUROPE/MINSK                                            EUR >> 26-FEB-2021 19:33:29

Comment: @vikaskumar - I would put that in a quick note to Oracle Support as a bug report. I don't think there is any reasonable explanation that can make this anything other than a bug - regardless of any settings anywhere.